# <div> tag disappears under a floated element, but a <p> tag or text does not?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Consider this line of code:

```css
#bluediv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#greendiv {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="bluediv">
  </div>
  <div id="greendiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

You will notice that since #greendiv disappears under the floated #bluediv. At first, I thought it was because `<div>` is a block-element but when I tried `<p>`, which is also a block-element, it behaves as below:

```css
#bluediv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#greendiv {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="bluediv">
  </div>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  Normal text
  <div id="greendiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

It wraps around the floated #bluediv instead (along with the normal text)!

Why do they behave differently?

Comment: You've changed more factors than the element name. The paragraph has content, the div does not.

Comment: @Quentin: I think that is part of the question.

Comment: @BoltClock - I don't know if the OP realizes that it's significant.

Comment: So you mean to say that if I place text inside the #greendiv, the result will be different? I tried it and what happened was that the text appear UNDER the #bluediv...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paragraph itself does not wrap around the float. Only its text does, along with the bare text between the paragraph and #greendiv (which resides in an anonymous block box).

And that's why you'll also notice that #greendiv is shifted down — it's because of the addition of the paragraph, and the anonymous block box that contains the bare text.

If you make #bluediv translucent, put the bare text in its own block element that you can target with CSS, and make the boxes of both block elements visible (i.e. and not completely transparent against the background), you can see what's really happening:

```css
#bluediv {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
#greendiv {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
p, span {
  display: block;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="bluediv">
  </div>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  <span>Normal text</span>
  <div id="greendiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in [9.5 Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats):

> Since a float is not in the flow, non-positioned block boxes created
>   before and after the float box flow vertically as if the float did not
>   exist. However, the current and subsequent line boxes created next to
>   the float are shortened as necessary to make room for the margin box
>   of the float.

Note only the line boxes are shortened, but following block elements aren't.

[image]

If you don't want this behavior, you can make the block sibling establish a Block Formatting Context (BFC):

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting
>   context […] must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same
>   block formatting context as the element itself.

[image]

```css
.bluediv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.greendiv {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden; /* Establish BFC */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="bluediv"></div>
  <div class="greendiv"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="bluediv"></div>
  <p>Paragraph</p>
  Normal text
  <div class="greendiv"></div>
</div>
```

The only difference between your examples is the presence of text, which pushes down the non-BFC block.